# UITesting Failure getting list of active application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

There is a button by clicking on the button it opens facebook login page and clicking on the done button it gets back to the main view controller.

Here is the code which I got by recording

```
 override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        XCUIApplication().launch()

 }

func testExample() {

        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.buttons["Button"].tap()
        app.buttons["Done"].tap()
}
```

But when I run the recording it gives error in the second line of `testExample()`
Here is the error:
 `UI Testing Failure - Failure getting list of active applications: AX error -25205`

Comment: Got same problem at the simple two tabbed application with switching tabs or tapping on elements or something.

Comment: have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to "Enable UI Atomation" on the device (Settings > Developper).

(I had to restart my device to make it effective)